# Linear Regression TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am currently working on a linear regression model to try and predict prices of certain shoes. After loading in the data frames for the training data and the data to test and dropping the unwanted columns, I am beginning to work with independent and dependent variable for the regression coefficients. Here was the set of code I ran and was able to get working:

```
    SourceData_train_independent = Training_Data.drop(['Sale Price'], axis = 1) # 
    Drop depedent variable from training dataset

    SourceData_train_dependent = Training_Data['Sale Price'].copy() # New dataframe 
    with only Dependent variable value for training dataset

    SourceData_test_independent = Test_Data.drop(['Sale Price'], axis = 1)

    SourceData_test_dependent = Test_Data['Sale Price'].copy()
```

When I ran the next block of code to scale the data:

```
    sc_X = StandardScaler()

    X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(SourceData_train_independent.values) #scale the 
    independent variables

    y_train = SourceData_train_dependent # scaling is not required for dependent 
    variable

    X_test = sc_X.transform(SourceData_test_independent)

    y_test = SourceData_test_dependent
```

I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType'
```

on the line:

```
    X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(SourceData_train_independent.values) #scale the 
    independent variables
```

Currently, the sale price variable is a float64, do I just need to change the datatype to a number value or is it a more complicated fix? I have already run the code:

```
    Training_Data["Sale Price"] = Training_Data["Sale 
    Price"].astype(str).str.strip().replace("",0).astype(float)

    Test_Data["Sale Price"] = Training_Data["Sale 
    Price"].astype(str).str.strip().replace("",0).astype(float)
```

Hopefully someone can help as I'm struggling with this project. I used the code from: https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-in-python-sklearn-vs-excel-6790187dc9ca
Thank you so much!

Comment: you using pandas with a pandas specific dtype.  The function needs numpy arrays with numeric dtypes.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the content of `SourceData_train_independent`?

Comment: You need to check the `shape` and `dtype` of `SourceData_train_independent.values`.  Is it `object` dtype.  Does `SourceData_train_independent.values.astype(float)` work?